# MySQL basic query question

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
k | Ecode | Typ | Score     |  
---+------+-----+-----------+  
 1 |    1 | NYS |    104.17 |  
 2 |    2 | NYS |    201.55 |  
 3 |    3 | NYS |    213.22 |  
 4 |    1 | AA  |    106.22 |  
 5 |    2 | AA  |    204.88 |  
 6 |    3 | AA  |    215.81 |
```

And I want to produce the following:

```
Ecode | NYS      | AA        |  
------+----------+-----------+  
    1 |   104.17 |    106.22 |  
    2 |   201.55 |    204.88 |  
    3 |   213.22 |    215.81 |
```

The ECode is the record identifier in common and Typ will be the column separator...

How do I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Hello John, please see the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns/9668036#9668036